# Capture network traffic for firefox in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I found this on stackoverflow for chrome, works fine
[Capture network traffic using selenium webdriver java 4.0v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64873842/capture-network-traffic-using-selenium-webdriver-java-4-0v)

But how can I achieve this with firefox?
I can get all the logs with this code:

```
  System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "/tmp/FFLogs.txt")
  FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions()
  options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE)
```

I get many log entries, but I do not figure out the ajax requests. How can I do this with firefox?